# Sharing a "configuration" between annotations

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I want to share a common "configuration" between multiple annotated classes. My initial approach was to point the annotations to a class which then extends the configuration class:

```
@MyAnnotation(config = SharedConfig.class)
class A {}

@MyAnnotation(config = SharedConfig.class)
class B {}

class SharedConfig extends BaseConfig{

   public SharedConfig(){
      super("abc",123)
   }
}
```

My initial approach was to find the SharedConfig type during annotation processing and instantiate it to find out the actual config. The problem is I can't instantiate the SharedConfig class during the actual processing...

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you can't instantiate the config class. But what you *can* do, is query which annotations **are on the config class**.

So, you could imagine the following system:

old way:

```
@Movie(
  name = "A Few Good Men",
  director = @Director(lastName = "Reiner", firstName = "Rob"),
  releaseYear = 1992,
  liked = true)
public class Foo {}

@Movie(
  name = "A Few Good Men",
  director = @Director(lastName = "Reiner", firstName = "Rob"),
  releaseYear = 1992,
  liked = true)
public class Bar {}
```

new way:

```
@Movie(
  name = "A Few Good Men",
  director = @Director(lastName = "Reiner", firstName = "Rob"),
  releaseYear = 1992)
public class Placeholder {
  // This class serves solely as a place to store the above annotation.
  private Placeholder() {}
}

@Movie(
  config = Placeholder.class,
  liked = true)
public class Foo {}

@Movie(
  config = Placeholder.class,
  liked = false)
public class Bar {}
```

Your rule would presumably be that anything explicitly set on the actual class is taken, and if there is nothing explicitly set but there is a 'config' class set, then the value from the annotation on that config class is taken.

Unfortunately, there's no (non-hacky) way to tell the difference between `@Foo` and `@Foo(value="")` when `Foo` is defined as `@interface Foo {String value() default "";}` - i.e. there is no way to differentiate an explicit setting of a value that is the same as the default value for a given anno parameter, so you can't actually use 'if you do not explicitly set it, then this defaulting mechanism applies' as a concept in annotations. Therefore, 'use the defaulting mechanism' must be based on the actual value - you need 'stand-in' values that mean: "Inherit from config". That means booleans are right out, unfortunately. You can use enums instead.

Here is an example:

```
public enum LikeStatus {
   LIKED, DISLIKED, INHERIT;
}

// target classes/types
public @interface Movie {
    Class<?> config() default Object.class;
    LikeStatus liked default LikeStatus.INHERIT;
    int releaseYear() default 0;
    Director director() default @Director(lastName = "", firstName = "")
    String name() default "";
}
```

and now you need to write some code that knows about the defaults and acts accordingly (so, if `name()` returns an empty string, that means you should check the `config` class for the `Movie` annotation and fetch its `name`. Same for a release year of 0, a director with a blank first and last name, and so on.